# Netlogo, rnd:weighted-one-of-list reports couples of values

Tags: netlogo

So, I'm using NetLogo and I'm trying to get a procedure which assigns each turtle a list of the hours of the day when they have to perform a certain task, which they have to do 6 times a day.

I want some hours to be more likely to be those where most turtles perform the task than others, because of this I used `rnd:weighted-n-of-list` in the following way below.

I can run the program, but then, if I inspect one of the turtles, insted of something like `action-time: [ 2 7 9 13 17 21 ]`, which is what I'm intending to get, they show `action-time: [[2 0.02] [7 0.04] [9 0.08] [13 0.04] [17 0.04] [21 0.04]]`.

I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong, I checked a couple of times that the weights sum 1.00 and the anonymous-reporter, but I can't still manage to get it to work as I would like to.

```
to probability
  let hours     [ 0      1      2       3       4       5       6      7      8      9      10     11     12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19     20     21     22     23  ]
  let weights   [ 0.04   0.04   0.02    0.02    0.02    0.02    0.04   0.04   0.08   0.08   0.08   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04   0.04]  
  let combination  (map list hours weights)
  ask tutles [
    set action-time rnd:weighted-n-of-list 6 combination [ [p] -> last p ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want only the first value of that list, you can use `first`:

```
set action-time map first rnd:weighted-n-of-list 6 combination [ [p] -> last p ]
```

Comment: Thanks @Lena , but I just tried that and, following the example that I said before, I'm getting something like `[2 0.02]` instead of `[ 2 7 9 13 17 21 ]` .  You just gave me the idea to add some code which kind of clears the list I am obtaining, but I'm still thinking there must be a (maybe) easier way to obtain that directly and skipping the step of rearranging the list with pairs I get.

Comment: Sorry, I tried that for one-of and not for n-of. I corrected my post, you can use `map first`

Comment: Just used the way you propposed and works perfectly, thank you! :)